# JS Audio sequence of notes from Oscillator with Sleep function

Tags: javascript, audio, javascript-oscillator

I'm trying to create a simple function `playTone(freq, dur)` that plays a tone at `freq` hertz for `dur` (milli-)seconds.

I'm having trouble getting the function to wait for the previous note to finish before starting a new one. My code is below, using a `sleep` function from this site. I don't yet understand the synchronous/async thing with JS, and I'd like to keep things as simple as possible. Can anyone help to make my code work please? At present the notes all play together.

```
<script>
function sleep (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, time));
}

function playTone(freq, dur) {
    var audio = new AudioContext();
    var osc = audio.createOscillator();
    var gainNode = audio.createGain()
    gainNode.gain.value = 0.2
    osc.frequency.value = freq;
    osc.type = "square";
    osc.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audio.destination);
    osc.start(0);
    osc.stop(dur);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    playTone(440 + 10 * i, 1);
    sleep(1000);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best approach, but you could create a recursive method, like this:

```
function playTone(freqs, idx, dur) {
    var audio = new AudioContext();
    var osc = audio.createOscillator();
    var gainNode = audio.createGain()
    gainNode.gain.value = 0.2
    osc.frequency.value = freqs[idx];
    osc.type = "square";
    osc.connect(gainNode);
    gainNode.connect(audio.destination);
    osc.start(0);

    setTimeout(function() {
        osc.stop(0); //Now setTimeout controls the stop
        if (freqs[idx + 1]) {
            playTone(freqs, idx + 1, dur);
        }
    }, dur);
}

var frequencies = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    frequencies.push(440 + 10 * i);
}

playTone(frequencies, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks but it need to be blocking and to play just one note at a time if needed. I want to use it to add sound to turtle graphics animations, with each turtle command accompanied by a tone. It needs to be callable outside of any function too...

Comment: The problem is, there is no delay or sleep on JS, so when you call setTimeout, which is the closest approach to sleep, unless the rest of your code is inside setTimeout function, it will keep running. In recursive function you could pass an array with just one frequency. Good luck! o/